# iptables FORWARD and INPUT

Tags: linux, input, iptables, forwarding

I have a home network with Linux pc's, which all had iptables running. I think it is easier to put my LAN behind a Linux gateway/firewall, so I've put a pc (with fedora,no gui) between my router and LAN and configured iptables. No problem here, INPUT only allows dns an http (and some local stuff), forwarding works fine: LAN connects to internet.

But my question is: does FORWARD allows all from the outside, or only the ports I configured with INPUT? Do FORWARD and INPUT work together or are they separate?

This is my iptables:

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [16:1336]
:INPUT ACCEPT [14:840]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [30:2116]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o p1p1 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Oct 16 09:55:31 2012
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.14 on Tue Oct 16 09:55:31 2012
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [91:9888]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p UDP --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p TCP --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -i p1p1 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 20,21 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.2.0/24 -i p3p1 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 20,21 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -i p1p1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5000:5100 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.2.0/24 -i p3p1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5000:5100 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i p1p1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.2.0/24 -i p3p1 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -i p1p1 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i p1p1 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 20,21,443 -j DROP
-A INPUT -i p1p1 -p tcp --dport 5000:5100 -j DROP
-A INPUT -i p1p1 -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j DROP
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.2.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.2.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables denied: " --log-level 7
-A OUTPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "denied out: "

COMMIT
```

p1p1 (.1.x) is my external nic, p3p1 (.2.x) is internal.

Comment: From the iptables tag: IPTABLES SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com. Use this tag only for questions on programming with iptables. Questions about configuring iptables should be asked on Server Fault (https://serverfault.com/). Please delete this.
I’m voting to close this question because

Answer (score 101):

RedHat has a **[great doc about iptables](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html-single/Security_Guide/index.html#sect-Security_Guide-Firewalls-Using_IPTables)** (a little bit long), but the subject to cover is complex and there are so many different use cases that I don't see how to avoid it.

[image: iptables kernel routing]

Here is the chapter about **[FORWARD and NAT Rules](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html-single/Security_Guide/index.html#sect-Security_Guide-Firewalls-FORWARD_and_NAT_Rules)**. As it states:

> For example, if you want to **forward incoming HTTP requests** to your
>   dedicated **Apache HTTP Server at 172.31.0.23**, use the following command
>   as the root user:

```
~]# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 172.31.0.23:80
```

Here is what happens:

- your linux gateway receives a packet from your router. The packet header has:

  - source: `x.x.x.x:y` (sender IP from the internet & source port used for packet transmission)
  - destination: `192.168.1.1:80` (assuming your linux gateway IP on external NIC, ie `p1p1`)
- your linux gateway applies the **PREROUTING** chain to find a match. Assuming that you have typed what's above, the **packet matches the rule** and then calls (jumps `-j`) to the **DNAT function** (*Destination Network Address Translation*) which **changes the destination of the packet header** from the initial `192.168.1.1:80` to `172.31.0.23:80`.
- then, the packet arrives to the **Routing Decision**. The packet destination is now `172.31.0.23:80`.

  - Your linux gateway asks itself: Is it for me (`192.168.1.1:80`) ? No, so I **won't send** it to the **INPUT** chain.
  - => I'll send it to the **FORWARD** chain.
- since you have set the rules to **FORWARD all on your local network** (table `filter` chain `FORWARD`), the packet should be forwarded correctly to your local Apache HTTP Server (for example).

Hope it'll help to understand a little bit more how internal routing works with iptables.

Comment: Thank you so much for that diagram! I wish I saw it earlier.

Comment: @torvin Second that notion, that's a very helpful diagram for novices.

Answer (score 78):

INPUT, FORWARD, and OUTPUT are separate. A packet will only hit one of the three chains.

If the destination is *to* this server, it hits the INPUT chain. If its source is *from* this server, it hits OUTPUT. If its source and destination are both other machines—it's being routed *through* the server—then it hits the FORWARD chain.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, I have INPUT secured (sort of), but FORWARD lets everything through the way it is now? I hoped traffic was first filtered by INPUT, and then forwarded.

Comment: Traffic from the outside, that is.

Comment: @Ray Right. A packet going through your box hits only FORWARDED. It doesn't do INPUT → FORWARDED → OUTPUT.

Comment: Allright, thank you for your answer. Is there a way with nat-rules I can route certain ports to my LAN? For example, block all, open port 53 for my whole LAN? I am not an expert at this, I know how to set up a firewall, but routing is different stuff.

Comment: I'm looking into bridging, see what I can do with that.

Comment: @Ray You can post that as a new question, and serverfault.com would be a better fit, more network experts there I'd imagine.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it there. Read a lot about bridging, it cannot do what I want. Think I have to dive into the realm of DNAT and SNAT.... John, thanks for thinking with me!