# How to setup fail2ban with Rancher Load Balancer (HAProxy)

Tags: haproxy, rancher, fail2ban, cattle

I want to setup fail2ban on my Rancher agents.

I have a Cattle environment running a managed network where each Rancher agent is running a HAProxy used as a web-server + load balancer.

I want to ban users based on different criteria (too many failed logins, too many requests, etc) from HTTP and HTTPs ports.

Currently I have fail2ban [setup with regex that is working](https://serverfault.com/a/853817/460025) in dummy logs but fail2ban is not banning any IPs.

`fail2ban-client status <my-jail>` shows that the jail has been started but has 0 bans even when I do incorrect requests.

Answer (score 0):

After running fail2ban in debug mode and investigating IP tables I have found the problem.

The problem occurs because of 3 reasons:

1) HAProxy is running a docker image with server time in UTC and your servers might be in a different time zone.

2) HAProxy is running in a docker container in a Cattle managed network which means that the incoming packets are [Forward packets and not Input packets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945233/iptables-forward-and-input/23436938#23436938) for iptables.

3) The way Cattle handles forwarding is a [bit ugly](https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/10387) and hence does not allow custom fail2ban rules

---

In my case as HAProxy is in a docker image with a different timezone, fail2ban was ignoring ban attempts as the time was a few hours off. Changing the server time fixed the first problem.

I could now see that IPs were indeed being banned when using:

`fail2ban-client status <my-jail>`

But the problem still remained cause even though I could see the correct IPs being banned, I could still access the server completely fine.

This is because of the way Rancher sets up iptables. To fix this problem I changed my /etc/fail2ban/jail.local from:

```
[DEFAULT]
...
chain = INPUT
...
```

To:

```
[DEFAULT]
...
chain = CATTLE_FORWARD
...
```

Now the users are correctly banned because the timezone matches and are then put into a jail in the Forward chain hence dropping requests from banned users.

Comment: Thank you for the candid feedback. We will try to address the issue of being able to add custom iptables rules in a easier way.